# Convert page scroll to scroll percentage of inner div

Tags: javascript, html, css

After getting my last problems solved properly I've got a second problem.
I've got a div which is fixed. Inside of the fixed div is another div which is scrollable. I want to achieve that if I scroll anywhere on the page, even out of the scrollable div, that the scroll action only applies to the scrollable div, not the fixed div.

I made an example of the problem. I want to achieve that if I am scrolling anywhere, even in the red part, that the scroll action is in the red div.

#### Demo:

```js
 $(window).scroll(function () {
   var s = $(this).scrollTop();
   var row1 = $('#row1');
   if(s>500){
        row1.css({
            'position': 'relative'
        });
   }
 
});
```

```css
.timeline {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
}

#row1 {
  width: 100vw;
  height:100vh;
  position: fixed;
  background-color:red;
}

.col-sm-6{width:50%;float:left;height:100px;}
#test{background-color:green;overflow-x:scroll;}
body{height:1000px}
```

```html
<div class="row" id="row1">
<div class="col-sm-6"></div>
<div class="col-sm-6" id="test">scrollable div<br>test1<br>test2<br>test3<br>test4<br>test5<br>test6<br>test7<br>test8<br>test9<br>test10<br>test11</div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Popper JS -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hey, sorry for bothering. I am pretty new to this platform and used it as a quiet reader so far. I am not sure of what I am supposed to do right now. Shall I change the previous question and expand it with the new question?

Comment: Good job on editing your question. I don't quite get it though... perhaps your example needs to set `height:200vh` to the red div? Please explain a bit more completely - read the question from the viewpoint of someone in a hurry who is a total stranger to your code / project. *Overall, much improved though.*

Comment: Thanks :) Let me try again: I to be able to have the cursor on the red div and scroll down. The thing that I want to achieve is, that through this action the green divs scroll down, even when the cursor is NOT on the green div.

I changed the code slightly and put a height to the body element.

Comment: @cssyphus I wanted to show, that the div should stay fixed, but only for the first 500 pixels. Afterwards it's supposed to be relative.

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(function () {
    var myCounter = 0,
        myOtherCounter = 0;
    var scroll = 0;

    $("#test").scroll(function () {
        myCounter = myCounter + 1;
        $("#log").html("<div>Handler for .scroll() called " + myCounter + " times.</div>");
    });

    //Firefox
    $('#row1').bind('DOMMouseScroll', function (e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.detail > 0) {
            scrollDown();
        } else {
            scrollUp();
        }

        //prevent page fom scrolling
        return false;
    });

    //IE, Opera, Safari
    $('#row1').bind('mousewheel', function (e) {
        if (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {
            scrollDown();
        } else {
            scrollUp();
        }
        //prevent page fom scrolling
        return false;
    });
    
    function scrollDown() {
        //scroll down
        console.log('Down ' + scroll);
        if (scroll < $('#test').find('div').height() - $('#test').height() + 20) {
            scroll = $('#test').scrollTop() + 5;
            $('#test').scrollTop(scroll);
        }
    };
    function scrollUp() {
        //scroll up
        console.log('Up ' + scroll);
        if (scroll > 0) {
            scroll = $('#test').scrollTop() - 5;
            $('#test').scrollTop(scroll);
        }
    };
});
```

```css
.timeline {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 1200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
}

#row1 {
  width: 100vw;
  height:50vh;
  position: fixed;
  background-color:red;
}

.col-sm-6{width:50%;float:left;height:100px;}
#test{background-color:green;overflow-x:scroll;}
body{height:1000px}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="row1">
<div class="col-sm-6" id="test"><div>scrollable div<br>test1<br>test2<br>test3<br>test4<br>test5<br>test6<br>test7<br>test8<br>test9<br>test10<br>test11</div></div>
  <div id="log"></div>
    <div id="log2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so far! This solution isn't working properly yet. As far as I begin to scroll the console always returns "down 0" and "up 0". And I can't scroll anywhere until I reload the page.

You removed the first div "col-sm-6". Would it be a difference if it was still in there? I am trying to solve the problem, but I don't know how.

Comment: try it on codepen(i modife html codes): https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pXbOob

Comment: Thanks so far. The code in codepen worked. But the javascript is still the same. And it doesn't work in mine code somehow. I still get down 0 and up 0. Any solutions?

Edit: I tried to understand your js. To make the scrolling work, the scroll var has to get bigger or smaller. But I can't find the part in the code which changes the scroll var.